# Should the on-change event in <paper-input> fire twice?

Tags: polymer

I've tried using `<core-input>` and "change" just fires once. Any ideas what could be the problem?

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <paper-input on-change="{{logChange}}">
  </template>
  <script> Polymer('my-element', {logChange: function(e){console.log('fired');}); </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Output:
fired
fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue - here's the corresponding Github issue:

https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/issues/33

It's looking like this may actually be a bug in Chrome, for which a fix is in the works:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=398527&thanks=398527&ts=1406661473